# What's a good way to schedule scripts that depend on each other?

Tags: scheduled-task, queue

So, I have a few scripts that need to be executed in order, and they need to wait for the previous script to finish since they need the data it gathers.

I thought about putting it all in a single script but I want to run it on a small VPS and it'd most likely run out of memory.

My first thought was about cron, but as the scripts depend on each other to finish first I'm not sure how I'd schedule them.

Then I thought about Celery, but it says it's focused on real time stuff and it seems a bit of an overkill for what I want.

Is there something simpler than Celery that I could use to achieve this?

Comment: See my answer in the duplicate above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they must be run in order, you can have the first script call the next script after it has successfully completed. But you will have to set up the criteria to ensure that it has completed successfully to your satisfaction. You can also have it so each script checks for a lock file, so that it won't run until the other script in the sequence has completed.